# Novice to square roots/math

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been asked to answer this question and I am just not quite sure if I have the correct answer this is all very new to me

Flame length = $\sqrt{(0.5\times  D)^2}+H^2$

$\sqrt{(0.5\times0.10)^2}+0.10 = \sqrt{41}/20$

$41/20 = 2.05$

is this the correct answer? If not how do I solve this.

Comment: What are $D$ and $H$?

Comment: For know if you right or not we have we have to know more details about your question....

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're supposed to plug in the values $D=0.1$ and $H=\sqrt{0.1}$ ? Anyway, it really puzzles me how you got something like $\sqrt{41}$ there, since under the root you're multiplying quantities that are all less than $1$. There's no way you'd get 41 like that. And why "divided by 20"??

Comment: @SoboKevSpace  "The formula you have looks odd you are asked to calculate $\sqrt{(ab)^2= \pm ab$"    NO!  There are two numbers, a and -a, whose square is $a^2$ but $\sqrt{a^2}$ is, by definition, the positive one.  $\sqrt{(ab)^2= |ab|$, NOT $\pm ab$.

Comment: @user247327 Sorry, I have no clue what your comment is trying to convey.

Comment: It was that $\sqrt{a^2}= |a|$, NOT $\pm a$.

Comment: 9 has two square roots, 3 and -3, which can be written as $\pm 3$.  HOWEVER, the square root function, because it is a **function** must return a single result.  $\sqrt{9}= 3$, not "$\pm  3$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be structural and take steps! Its better to write more steps than making mistakes by skipping them. So your equation:
$$\text{Flame length} = \sqrt{(0.5D)^2}+H^2$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ = 0.5|D|+H^2$$

Where the straight lines mean take the absolute value. This means that if $D$ is negative, you multiply it with $-1$.

Best to keep variables variable as long as possible. This helps you with keeping oversight and if you want to validate different values, you can easily plug them in. At this moment, the equation really cannot be simplified further. So now you can plug them in and compute the answer. Remember the mathematical equation order (so which things should you solve first).

So assuming $H = 0.1$ and $D = 0.1$, the solution should be:
$$0.5\times0.1 + 0.1^2 = 0.05 + 0.01 = 0.06$$

Comment: sorry I should have given more information
D = 0.10 Flame base
H = 0.10 Flame Flame height

I am being asked to workout the flame length with this data and the formula to work it out is the one above, thanks for all the feedback

Comment: how come these numbers haven't been squared?

Comment: With the given numbers, I have changed the result. Since I had to guess the actual values, I assumed you took $H^2 = 0.1$, so the value was already squared. Also maybe a dummy suggestion, but it might not be a bad idea to see some youtube videos about basic math operations. I still cannot figure out how you got to your solution ;-)